# How to open target=_blank links inside WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, href

My android app contains WebView. And one of the pages contains an **Iframe** and it contain
 an 'a tag' with **target='_blank'**. Is there any way to open that link inside my WebView instead of external browser?

I tried and failed catch 'a tag' click inside **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** and **shouldInterceptRequest** methods.

Comment: Did you find something because I am trying to do the same.